# Language field on Case

Tags: case, language, standard-field

I can find a Standard field Language on Case object on my Production org, which as per [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cases_fields.htm&type=5) should also be available in my sandbox, but isn't.
Any pointers why this is happening?
Or is my sandbox not an "org with Service Cloud" but Production is?

[image]

Comment: You can try on the sandbox click “match production licenses” button from “company information” menu in setup

Comment: your info is useful, I also went through the implications and preconsiderations of using this here https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335272&type=1, I will pass it over to my admin, as I am not in control of this. Will update in this answer when we exactly locate which license is causing it.